# Web service asp.net POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http, post

Based on this tutorial (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405189/How-to-access-SQL-database-from-an-iPhone-app-Via)

I try to do a WebServices in asp.net.
the GET method works... but the POST method don't.
(I verify with the app of chrome "POSTMAN") and have and error: 
***Error 404, no found
End not found***

I hope u can help me with that, i'm started with web services.

code ASP.net
**The Interface**

```
namespace JsonWcfService {
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGetEmployees
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/employees")]
    List<Employee> GetAllEmployeesMethod();
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPostEmployees
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}")]
    bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1, string id2);
}
```

}

**The WFC**

```
namespace JsonWcfService
{
 public class GetEmployees : IGetEmployees 
 {
   public List<Employee> GetAllEmployeesMethod()
    {
         List<Employee> mylist = new List<Employee>();

         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=SQLREPORTES;database=prueba;persist security info=True;user id=myuser;password=mypassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string cmdStr = String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.EmpDB");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    mylist.Add(new Employee(rd.GetString(0), rd.GetString(1))); //, rd.GetDecimal(2)));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return mylist;
    }
   //insert to DataBase
   public bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1, string id2)
   {
       int success = 0;
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=SQLREPORTES;database=prueba;persist security info=True;user id=myuser;password=mypassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"))
       {
           conn.Open();

           //decimal value = Decimal.Parse(id3);
           string cmdStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.EmpDB VALUES('{0}','{1}')", id1, id2);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
           success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           conn.Close();
       }
       return (success != 0 ? true : false);
   }
   public bool UseHttpGet { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
    public Employee(string first, string last)
    {
        firstname=first;
        lastname=last;
        //salary=sal;
    }
}
```

}

And the web.config (Download [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebbgaly7dtu4s4s/Web.config?dl=0))

```
<services>
  <service name="JsonWcfService.GetEmployees" behaviorConfiguration="EmpServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JsonWcfService.IGetEmployees" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
 </services>
```

Comment: Please note that "don't." is not very detailed explanation of the problem you have. Try to add/highlight code that actually related to POST request you mentioned in the title as well expected/observed behavior.

Comment: You rigth, i Gonna edit, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your Web.config you're using the contract IGetEmployees which doesn't have a definition for your InsertEmployee method thus you need to merge the two interfaces in one interface and modify your web.config instead of

```
contract="JsonWcfService.IGetEmployees"
```

with `contract="JsonWcfService.IEmployees"` IEmployees define your two methods the get and post method

Comment: Yes, Thank you.. thats is correct, i didn't call it... now my miskate is Error 404, i gonna look that.